# I want to create a generic selector for 2D array in C

Tags: c, generics, late-binding

In case if 2d array is of float type I want to call the first function and otherwise the second, how can I accomplish this?

```
 void printff(int n,float m[n][n])
    {
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        printf("\t%f",m[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
        }
    }
    
void printfi(int n,int m[n][n])
{
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
    printf("\t%d",m[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
    }
}

#define print(a,b) _Generic(b,int*[sizeof(a)]:printfi,float*[sizeof(a)]:printff)(a,b)
```

Comment: `sizeof(a)` just gives you the size of an int in bytes, that's why this code doesn't work.

Comment: ya I noticed it but I actually meant sizeof(b)

Answer (score 6):

The macro should be:

```
#define print(a,b) _Generic((b), int(*)[]: printfi, float(*)[]: printff)((a), (b))
```

the type of `b` is either `int(*)[a]` or `float(*)[a]`, e.g. a pointer to an array of `a` `int` or `float`.

This code works for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printff(int n,float m[n][n])
{
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
            printf("\t%f",m[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
    
void printfi(int n,int m[n][n])
{
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
            printf("\t%d",m[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

#define print(a,b) _Generic((b), int(*)[]: printfi, float(*)[]: printff)((a), (b))

int main()
{
    float a[5][5];
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
            a[i][j] = i * 5 + j;
    print(5, a);
    int b[2][2];
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
            b[i][j] = i * 2 + j;
    print(2, b);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/zrP9TnEcP

If you only use square 2D arrays, you can use this macro:

```
#define print(a) _Generic((a), int(*)[]: printfi, float(*)[]: printff)(sizeof *(a) / sizeof **(a), a)
```

It will calculate the length itself. Call it with `print(a);` or `print(b);`.

https://godbolt.org/z/xP918sn1s

It can be even easier when you use `**(a)` for the first parameter of `_Generic`:

```
#define print(a) _Generic(**(a), int: printfi, float: printff)(sizeof *(a) / sizeof **(a), (a))
```

https://godbolt.org/z/TzrY1G4ev

Comment: The array dimensions are not needed in the `_Generic`; it will accept and match incomplete types: `#define print(a) _Generic((a), int (*)[] : printfi, float (*)[] : printff)(sizeof *(a) / sizeof **(a), (a))` works. Also, the macro arguments should be parenthesized in the replacement text, as usual. And please do not write code without spaces for readability. Just because it is called “code” does not mean it has to be hard to read.

Comment: @EricPostpischil thanks. Even with the incomplete types, I prefer the version with `_Generic(**(a), int: ....`.